# Texture Paint a straight Line using Python

Tags: python, texture-painting

Refactoring this post to simplify the request:

I need to draw a straight line/continuous Stroke in Python with Texture Paint. Unfortunately it is currently only placing a single dot at either end of the stroke.

Desired Outcome:

[image]

Current Code does this:

[image]

Tried:

- Using "location" & "mouse_event" instead of mouse
- Making "name" unique
- Using different Stroke settings in Texture Paint (like Line)
- UV unwrapping
- Every combination of "is_start" for each stroke

I've seen multiple posts about this with no solutions, is bpy.ops.paint.image_paint just broken?

Code:

```
import bpy

x1 = 500
x2 = 800
# the line should be horizontal, ie 500-800px

strokes = [{"name": "",
    "is_start": True,
    "location": (0,0,0),
    "mouse":(x1, 500),
    "mouse_event":(0,0),
    "pen_flip":False,
    "pressure":1.0,
    "size":10,
    "time":0,
    "x_tilt":0.0,
    "y_tilt":0.0}, 

    {"name": "",
    "is_start": False,
    "location": (0,0,0),
    "mouse":(x2, 500),
    "mouse_event":(0,0),
    "pen_flip":False,
    "pressure":1.0,
    "size":10,
    "time":0,
    "x_tilt":0.0,
    "y_tilt":0.0}]  
    
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='TEXTURE_PAINT')

areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']

with bpy.context.temp_override(
    window=bpy.context.window,
    area=areas[0],
    region=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
    screen=bpy.context.window.screen
):
    bpy.ops.paint.brush_select(vertex_tool="DRAW", toggle=False)
    bpy.ops.paint.image_paint(stroke=strokes)
```

Comment: I'm on Blender 3.6 and nothing happens. Are you sure your code works? the `bpy.ops` statement will even error out as poll context fail. so i updated it to be executed in the [right context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add). it runs without errors now but nothing happens. Not even a dot gets painted.

Comment: thanks for adding the context override, i was in the middle of adding it but you were faster ;)

the rest should work, it works on my end (it's an operator in a bigger addon), i just don't understand why it doesn't paint a continuous line, i've tried in 3.3 and 3.6

edit: try adding a plane, and zooming in so the plane covers the full 3d view, then try running the operator, since it's using fixed x/y values if you're zoomed out it might be "missing" the mesh

Comment: oooh ok. cool now i see the 2 dots drawn. now something i can work on.

Comment: sweet, i appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the way it works where we expected it to fill the gap. You have to manually define the points where a stroke will be applied:

```
import bpy

points = []

for i in range(0,800):
    points.append((i*6,500))

strokes = []
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    stroke = {
        "name": "",
        "is_start": True,
        "location": (0, 0, 0),
        "mouse": point,
        "mouse_event": (0, 0),
        "pen_flip": False,
        "pressure": 1.0,
        "size": 10,
        "time": 0,
        "x_tilt": 0.0,
        "y_tilt": 0.0
    }
    strokes.append(stroke)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='TEXTURE_PAINT')

areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']

with bpy.context.temp_override(
    window=bpy.context.window,
    area=areas[0],
    region=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
    screen=bpy.context.window.screen
):
    bpy.ops.paint.brush_select(image_tool="DRAW", toggle=False)
    bpy.ops.paint.image_paint(stroke=strokes)
```

Comment: damn unfortunately to get a rectangle I'd have to call this line operator with a 1px size a few hundred times using a nested loop and it's just extremely slow, I was hoping Blender had a way to draw the strokes continuously

i appreciate your help anyway!

Comment: but im not 100% sure if there is another way, there is unfortunately not enough documentation on this.

Comment: ill dig into the source a bit and see if there's anything but I don't have high hopes considering the previous posts asking similar questions